# SQL exception not caught

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I have a SQL script that doesn't cause an exception in my C# code.

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2)
OUTPUT inserted.ID
VALUES ('ABC', 'DEF')

MERGE MY_OTHER_TABLE T
USING
  (
    SELECT
      ID
      ,COLUMN1
      ,COLUMN2
    FROM MY_TABLE
  ) S
  ON
  T.MY_TABLE_ID = S.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (
      MY_TABLE_ID
    )
  VALUES
    (
      S.ID
    );

COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN

  DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
  DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
  DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

  SELECT
    @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

  RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
END CATCH
```

In my C# code I will execute the statement:

```
await using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    if (await reader.ReadAsync())
    { 
        return (long)reader["ID"];
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now if an error occurs in the `MERGE` (for example an update or delete more than one exception), I don't get it in my C# code.

I now know why. The insert is still error-free. Since this returns a data series with the OUTPUT, I can still read it. The exception only arises afterwards in the MERGE from or after which I no longer expect any data series.

If I continued to select data after the MERGE, the `reader.NextResult()` in C# would throw an exception because the `MERGE` is before the next selection, in which an error occurs.

Now my question: how do you guarantee in such cases that you get every exception up to the C# code?

Comment: Why are you using try/catch _inside_ the SQL command? The only thing it does is rollback the transaction. C# can manage the transaction itself.

Comment: Reader may be null or EOF.

Comment: @gunr2171 I will handle TRANSACTIONS via SQL NOT IN C#

Comment: @jdweng rhe Reader is not NULL and there is no EOF. I will get the ID of the new Row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error handling is **awful**. It swallows the error (possibly multiple) so C# doesn't see it, passes back a spurious `SELECT` with a single error message, then re-raises that single error using `RAISERROR` which does not give the correct error number.

Just use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to ensure rollback

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
  (
    COLUMN1
    ,COLUMN2
  )
OUTPUT
  inserted.ID
VALUES
  (
    'ABC'
    ,'DEF'
  )

MERGE MY_OTHER_TABLE T
USING
  (
    SELECT
      ID
      ,COLUMN1
      ,COLUMN2
    FROM MY_TABLE
  ) S
  ON
  T.MY_TABLE_ID = S.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT
    (
      MY_TABLE_ID
    )
  VALUES
    (
      S.ID
    );

COMMIT;
```

Then in C# use a normal `try` `catch` block to catch any errors.

You also need to call `NextResult()` if there is any chance that later statements can cause an error.

```cs
try
{
    await using var connection = ...
    await using var cmd =  ...
    cmd.Parameters.Add ...
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    await using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    long? id = null;
    if (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        id = (long)reader["ID"];
    }

    while (await reader.NextResultAsync())
    { }

    return id;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // error handling here
}
```

Side note: your query is slightly strange, as it merges the *entirety* of `MY_TABLE` even though you inserted one value.

Also I hope you are using parameters in the query.

Comment: And the SET XACT_ABORT ON; do not solve my problem.

Comment: No, but it removes the need for the `BEGIN CATCH` and `ROLLBACK`. It's the C# side where you need to catch the error.

Comment: Do you mean that the whole script wasn't actually representative? You need to show what you are actually doing, otherwise it's hard to give definite advice.

Comment: This excample is my problem in simple! My problem is that i dont get the Exception.

Comment: You need to loop `NextResult` if the error is happening in the merge. See edit.

Comment: Thank you... NextResult() is my Solution!